# Otto communicating from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, otto

I've been playing with Otto for the last few days and it's just amazing. However, I've run into a problem, I"m trying to communicate from a Fragment to the Activity. To keep things simple, I have one Activity which hold the Fragment, and in the Fragment I have a Button which just simply posts an event.

```
@Inject Bus bus;
...
...
bus.post(new ReadStatusEvent("23"));
```

In the Activity I have a Subscribe method.

```
@Subscribe
public void onReadStatusEvent(ReadStatusEvent event){
    Timber.i("sub:"+event.getReadStatusID());
}
```

Here is the event

```
public class ReadStatusEvent {
  private final String readStatusID;

  public ReadStatusEvent(String readStatusID) { this.readStatusID = readStatusID; }

  public String getReadStatusID() { return readStatusID; }
}
```

I'm using Dagger, so my Otto Bus is a singleton which is Injected by the SimpleModule file.

```
@Provides @Singleton
Bus provideBus() {
    return new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
}
```

I've been going at it for the whole day but for some reason the Subscribe method is never called.

**Edit:** I've just tried using the [Otto plugin for Android Studio](https://github.com/square/otto-intellij-plugin) and whenever I click the @Subscribe or bus.post(..), it keeps searching but doesn't find anything(No usage found so far). I guess I'm doing something terribly wrong somewhere.

Comment: The plugin is currently broken, so it's not you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your hint concerning the Otto Plugin made me think about your imports.

Are you sure you are using "com.squareup.otto.Subscribe" and not "com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe" or any other package?

Comment: FML! You are right I never noticed the import, just changed it and it's working flawlessly now. THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive events, a class instance needs to register with the bus. Are you registering the objects holding your subscribers/producers?

```
bus.register(this); // Example
```

Comment: Yes, I have it in the onStart() of Activity and Fragment.